# Transform a vector to a 3-dimensional matrix

Tags: arrays, r, matrix

I want this vector

```
v <- c(111,112,121,122,211,212,221,222)
```

to be transformed into a 3-dimensional matrix, so that the outcome looks like:

```
,,1
111 112
121 122
,,2
211 212
221 222
```

Using `dim(v) <- c(2,2,2)` results in a structure like

```
,,1
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  111  121
[2,]  112  122

,,2  
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  211  221
[2,]  212  222
```

I guess there is a very easy way to do this, but I guess I use the wrong keywords in Google. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to know what you are doing in general, but for your given example, I see that after `dim(v) <- c(2,2,2)`, the resulting array differs from your expected output by a transpose / permutation. So I do

```
aperm(v, c(2,1,3))
```

That is, we are doing:

```
for (i in 1:2) v[,,i] <- t(v[,,i])
```